# Angular cli update error

Tags: angular, typescript

All I am trying to do is update my angular project which was version 4 to version 6. I upadated the angualr cli(`by npm uninstall -g angular-cli and after installing again`) after attempts to upgrade to version 6 failed with errors. after installing the new angular cli I am now getting this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\new-front\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\new-front\node_modules\angular-ide\bin\ng:39:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

How can I solve this and also upgrade my existing project to version 6, i hope i didn't mess my project up.  I have spent more than 2 hours trying to find a solution.

```
This is my package.json now

      {
  "name": "new-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.38",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Since I realized it was not advisable to upgrade from version 4 to 6. I did an upgrade from 4 to 5 and that is when I received this error posted below. and this drove me to uninstall and reinstall my angular cli which is now coursing me the problems stated above.

```
    new-front@0.0.0 C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\new-front
+-- @angular/animations@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/cli@1.6.2
| +-- @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.42
| | `-- rxjs@5.5.10  deduped
| `-- rxjs@5.5.10  deduped
+-- @angular/common@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/forms@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/http@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.10  invalid
+-- @angular/platform-server@5.2.10
+-- @angular/router@5.2.10  invalid
+-- angular-ide@0.9.38
| `-- angular-ide-loader@0.9.13
|   `-- typescript@2.4.2
`-- rxjs@5.5.10
```

Comment: share your package.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you entered the wrong command for installing the angular-cli, it should be

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Second, jumping from version 4 to 6 is not recommended because you are moving from major versions ( even numbers ).

Third, you have this error `\new-front\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli'` and please  check why you have `ember-cli` included there.

Lastly, there's a helpful upgrade guide [here](https://update.angular.io/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean I deleted first the cli and reinstalled so the command i posted for uninstalling.

2. True I also realised the same point that jumping from version 4 to 6 is not advicable , so I wasnt planning to do that. But I tried updating to version 5 and I was receiving this error.(I have posted it in the edited version of the main question). That is when I decided to uninstall and reinstall the angular cli again. 

3. The ember-cli cannot be found in the node modules

Comment: try to delete the node_modules again and run `npm cache clean --force` before doing `npm install`

Comment: I am now getting this error `module.js:549 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server' ` when i try to run the project. Can you take a look at my package.json which I am have uploaded the angular cli is now 6.0.1 and all other dependencies 4.0.0. I am thinking of reversing it back. Dont know what else to do. What do you suggest

Comment: with this kind of problem, you error could be coming from somewhere else. I could try to download your repo and install it on my machine though